# How to make installed apps executable by lambda user when using docker

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, pulumi, pulumi-python

I'm using a docker image on AWS lambda. In my dockerfile, I've installed an executable (the pulumi cli tool) and confirmed successful installation by running `RUN pulumi -version`.

When I try to invoke this executable through my lambda, I get permission denied errors from python Popen:

```
2023-01-25T14:41:45 ws = pulumi.automation.LocalWorkspace(work_dir="/tmp/", pulumi_home="/tmp/.pulumi")
2023-01-25T14:41:45 File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pulumi/automation/_local_workspace.py", line 125, in __init__
2023-01-25T14:41:45 pulumi_version = self._get_pulumi_version()
2023-01-25T14:41:45 File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pulumi/automation/_local_workspace.py", line 411, in _get_pulumi_version
2023-01-25T14:41:45 result = self._run_pulumi_cmd_sync(["version"])
2023-01-25T14:41:45 File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pulumi/automation/_local_workspace.py", line 430, in _run_pulumi_cmd_sync
2023-01-25T14:41:45 return _run_pulumi_cmd(args, self.work_dir, envs, on_output)
2023-01-25T14:41:45 File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pulumi/automation/_cmd.py", line 55, in _run_pulumi_cmd
2023-01-25T14:41:45 with subprocess.Popen(
2023-01-25T14:41:45 File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/stdlib.py", line 193, in sentry_patched_popen_init
2023-01-25T14:41:45 rv = old_popen_init(self, *a, **kw)  # type: ignore
2023-01-25T14:41:45 File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
2023-01-25T14:41:45 self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
2023-01-25T14:41:45 File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1821, in _execute_child
2023-01-25T14:41:45 raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
2023-01-25T14:41:45 PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'pulumi'[INFO]
```

I think this is a generic lambda permissions issue, but some extra context in case it is helpful: I'm using the pulumi-python library, which invokes this pulumi cli app via `subprocess`.

How can I ensure that things I install in my Dockerfile are executable by the lambda user?

Directions I tried:

- `chmod -R a+wrx /root/.pulumi` - this command runs ok but I still get the permission error when trying to invoke the executable
- I notice that my lambda user is `sbx_user1051`, so I tried to `chown -R sbx_user1051 /root/.pulumi` - this fails, saying there is no such user. That makes it seem like the lambda user is created after I deploy my docker image

Comment: What is the specific error you're getting (or, how do you know that `/root/.pulumi` is the problem)? What does your Dockerfile look like?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I resolved this by moving the installation out of the /root folder into the folder lambda uses as the workspace for task execution:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9-x86_64

RUN yum install -y \
    tar \
    gzip \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    which \
    && yum clean all

# install pulumi - this will go to the current user's home: /root
RUN curl -fsSL https://get.pulumi.com | sh

# move pulumi to the lambda function's task root folder
RUN mv /root/.pulumi/ ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT} 

# grant appropriate permissions
RUN chmod -R a+wrx ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/.pulumi

RUN chmod a+x ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/.pulumi/bin/pulumi

# add to path
ENV PATH="${PATH}:${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/.pulumi/bin"

...
```